# Using sumproduct instead of countif with closed workbooks

Tags: excel

I need to count some cells based on one criteria (date) in a closed workbook.  I'm using the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('[Q SHIP LIST III.xlsx]SHIP LIST'!$C$2:$C$20000 =$A2))
```

I've tried all sorts of coercers (--, +0, and *1) as well as using ctrl+shift+enter to make it an array, but for some reason the cell always ends up blank, not usually errors, just blank.  I know the count isn't 0 and I know all the data is within those 20000 cells.

Any help would be much appreciated, every site just tells me to do more of the same.

Comment: And I'm in excel 2010

Comment: Your formula works fine for me. I am using Excel for Mac 2011 though and the name of the file is automatically expanded with its full path when I paste the formula.

Comment: Any idea as to why it might not work for me?  I mean it's not giving me an error, it's just coming up blank, what does that mean? @ReinierTorenbeek

Comment: Could part of the issue be that I'm getting the data from a pivot table?

Comment: I guess the only way to figure out is break down your problem to a more simple case first. You could start with referring to a single cell in your closed workbook and see if it shows up properly. If it does, then compare that cell to a value and see the result, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=SUMPRODUCT(--('[Q SHIP LIST III.xlsx]SHIP LIST'!$C2:$C20000+0 = A2))

While dealing with a different part of the same spreadsheet I got my answer here and applied it to this problem, too:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/790143-sumproduct-incorrectly-returning-0-a.html

I had used my +0 coercer incorrectly it seems.